# Broadcasting two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have 2 dataframes as follow:

1st dataframe `data`:

```
             2019-06-19     2019-06-20     2019-06-21     2019-06-22     2019-06-23     2019-06-24     2019-06-25
 currency                                                                                                         
BCH          485.424079     485.424079      57.574609      57.559609      57.559609      57.559609      57.559609
BTC          202.204572     256.085103     197.291801     177.359726     177.359726     177.359726     252.859726
BTG         4065.370000    4065.370000    4065.370000    4065.370000    4065.370000    4065.370000    4065.370000
ETC        40001.000000   40001.000000   40001.000000   40001.000000   40001.000000   40001.000000       0.000000
ETH         4092.917231    4092.917231    1497.655594    1497.655594    1497.655594    1497.655594    1497.655594
```

2nd dataframe `sys_bal`:

```
created_at  2019-06-19  2019-06-20  2019-06-21  2019-06-22  2019-06-23  2019-06-24  2019-06-25
 currency                                                                                      
1WO            1997308     1996908     1996908     1996908     1996908     1996908     1996908
ABX             241444      241444      241444      241444      241444      241444      241444
ADH            5981797     5981797     5981797     5981797     5981797     5981797     5981797
ALX             385466      385466      385466      385466      385466      385466      385466
AMLT           4749604     4749604     4749604     4687869     4687869     4687869     4687869
BCH               4547        4547        4483        4463        4465        4467        4403
BRC            1231312     1231312     1231312     1231312     1231312     1231312     1231142
BTC               7366        7342        7287        7307        8292        8635        7772
BTRN          15236038    15236038    15236038    15236038    15236038    15236233    15236233
```

I try to add one with the other by doing `pos_bal = sys_bal + data`. They have the same size but i have an error.

the error:

```
pos_bal = sys_bal + data
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 1547, in f
other = _align_method_FRAME(self, other, axis)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 1481, in _align_method_FRAME
right = to_series(right)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 1456, in to_series
given_len=len(right)))
ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 7: given 2
```

I printed the dtypes of both dataframes and I got the following:

1st dataframe:

```
2019-06-19    float64
2019-06-20    float64
2019-06-21    float64
2019-06-22    float64
2019-06-23    float64
2019-06-24    float64
2019-06-25    float64
dtype: object
```

2nd dataframe:

```
   created_at
0  2019-06-19    int64
   2019-06-20    int64
   2019-06-21    int64
   2019-06-22    int64
   2019-06-23    int64
   2019-06-24    int64
   2019-06-25    int64
 dtype: object
```

`data.info()` output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 12 entries, BCH to XRP
Data columns (total 7 columns):
2019-06-20    12 non-null float64
2019-06-21    12 non-null float64
2019-06-22    12 non-null float64
2019-06-23    12 non-null float64
2019-06-24   12 non-null float64
2019-06-25    12 non-null float64
2019-06-26   12 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(7)
memory usage: 768.0+ bytes
None
```

`sys_bal.info()` output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
 Index: 126 entries, 1WO to ZPR
 Data columns (total 7 columns):
 2019-06-20    126 non-null int64
 2019-06-21    126 non-null int64
 2019-06-22    126 non-null int64
 2019-06-23    126 non-null int64
 2019-06-24    126 non-null int64
 2019-06-25    126 non-null int64
 2019-06-26    126 non-null int64
 dtypes: int64(7)
 memory usage: 7.9+ KB
 None
```

Comment: how working `pos_bal = sys_bal.add(data)` ? Are both DataFrames?

Comment: it does not work. I have the same error. Yes they are both dataframes

Comment: Cannot reproduce, probably because you to not give enough details on how to create the initial dataframes. A simple copy paste is good for trivial dataframes (a simple RangeIndex as index and a simple str Index with no name for columns) but as soon as non trivial indices or columns are involved you **must** give Python code to create the dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'currency':['BCH','BTC'],'2019-06-19 ':['485.424079','202.204572'],'2019-06-20':['485.424079','256.085103']})
sys_bal=pd.DataFrame({'currency':['1WO','ABX'],'2019-06-19 ':['1997308','241444'],'2019-06-20':['1996908','241444']})
```

EDIT: if you receiving `'dict' object has no attribute 'set_index'`
it means that you are not using dataframes as I expect, try use on your data:

```
data=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
sys_bal=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sys_bal)
data=data.set_index('currency')
sys_bal=sys_bal.set_index('currency')

df=pd.concat([data,sys_bal])
print(df)
         2019-06-19   2019-06-20
currency                        
BCH       485.424079  485.424079
BTC       202.204572  256.085103
1WO          1997308     1996908
ABX           241444      241444
```

it should works for you, if doesnt maybe try to look at your dataframes i see that in `sys_bal` you have additional header name `created_at`

Comment: oh i thought you want to add two dataframes? what is `data`?

Comment: `data` is the 1st dataframe

Comment: `    pos_bal = pd.concat([pos_bal,data])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 225, in concat
    copy=copy, sort=sort)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 286, in __init__
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'dict'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid`

Comment: The same problem again. It considers `data` the dataframe is dict. But it should not be dict. how to make it definitively a df please? the error is `'dict' object has no attribute 'set_index'`

Comment: @mama dede see my edits, you give us wrong examples i think, you are not using dataframes, i did the conversion before you setting index from dict to dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Problem is second DataFrame have `MultIindex` in columns, so need remove it first by [`Index.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.droplevel.html):

```
data.columns = data.columns.droplevel(0)
pos_bal = sys_bal + data
```

Comment: @mamadede - Ok, so what is `print (data.info())` and `print (sys_bal.info())` ?

Comment: I have added `info` to the data